# How to draw an arc between known points to draw XNOR gate in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

[image]

I want to draw an arc between point E to point G , F to H  ( I want to draw XNOR gate symbol )
I tried this way

```
path.moveTo(72,10); // for E --> G
QRect bound1 (52,10,20,60);
path.arcTo(bound1,90,-180);

QPainterPath path1;  // for F --> H 
path1.moveTo(104,10);
QRect bound2 (72,10,32,60);
path1.arcTo(bound2,90,-180);
```

and it is currently looking like this.
[image]

Comment: @Matti  I tried what you had said in my earlier question but it is not working. May be somewhere I have made a mistake.  Can you help me ?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but If drawing electronic symbols manually isn't a part of exercise, you could go with another way.. Qt support vector formats like swg. It might be  more effective dynamic-memory allocation-wise. If you're drawing an element as an item in  QGraphicsScene, that might be a solution, because SWGs of standard symbols may be  available and are easy to be modified as external resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your `QRect`. Your hand-drawn picture has the arc `E--->G` to the right of X coordinate 72. But `QRect bound1` starts at 52, not 72. Per the docs

> Creates an arc that occupies the given rectangle ...
> Note that this function connects the starting point of the arc to the current position if they are not already connected.

You don't want the connection part; you just want the arc itself. So the rectangle for E-H must have E and H as the top-left and bottom-left corners.